# My table is cut in half and it dosen't show anything below that, how do I fix it?

Tags: c#, html, resolution

When viewing on browser with a 100% resolution of the screen, my table gets cut in half and I can't see it all, I want to see everything with normal resolution, without having to change it to 90% everytime I open the website. I tried but I faild to fix it, please help me.

This is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <table class="w-100" style="height: 526px; margin-bottom: 100px">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="height: 53px" colspan="3"><center><h2>PROFILE</h2></center></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 500px">&nbsp;
                <div class="contact-info bg-white shadow-lg">
                    <center><h5 class="mb-3">Your information</h5></center>
                    <table class="w-100">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 35px">
                                <img src="icons/user.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                <p>Username</p>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 35px">
                                <img src="icons/key.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                <p>Password</p>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 35px">
                                <img src="icons/email.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                <p>Email</p>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="20px">
                            <td style="width: 35px" >
                                <img src="icons/birthdayCake.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                <p>Birth Date</p>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td style="width: 35px">
                                <a class="custom-btn btn custom-link" href="#section_1"><img src="icons/editUser.png" /></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
            <td style="width: 500px">&nbsp;
                <div class="contact-info bg-white shadow-lg">
                    <center><h5 class="mb-3">Your recipes</h5></center>
                    <table class="w-100">
                        <tr height="20px">
                            <td style="width: 35px; height: 20px;">
                                <img src="icons/recipe.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="height: 20px">
                                <br />
                                <p>My recipe 1</p>
                            </td>
                            <td style="height: 20px"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 35px; height:20px">
                                <img src="icons/recipe.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                <p>My recipe 2</p>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 35px">
                                <img src="icons/recipe.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                <p>My recipe 3</p>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 35px">
                                <img src="icons/recipe.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                <p>My recipe 4</p>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td style="width: 35px">
                                <a class="custom-btn btn custom-link" href="#section_1"><img src="icons/addRecipe.png" /></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
            <td style="width: 500px">
                <div class="contact-info bg-white shadow-lg">
                    <center><h5 class="mb-3">Recipes you've used</h5></center>
                    <table class="w-100">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 35px">
                                <img src="icons/recipe.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                <p>A recipe 1</p>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 35px">
                                <img src="icons/recipe.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                <p>A recipe 2</p>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 35px">
                                <img src="icons/recipe.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                <p>A recipe 3</p>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 35px">
                                <img src="icons/recipe.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                <p>A recipe 4</p>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td style="width: 35px">
                                <a class="custom-btn btn custom-link" href="#section_1"><img src="icons/search1.png" /></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

I tried everything but I just can't fix it. In 100% it just cuts it, but in 90% you can see everything. How do I fix it so you could see everything without shrinking your screen?

[In 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbb9O.jpg)

[In 90%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXdjh.jpg)

Comment: This is not tabular data and as such a table is the wrong way to start with. Code cleanly and semantically. COme back if the issue then still persist. There is no reason to fix a code from our side which is mainly caused by incorrect usage of the tools.

Comment: I understand, but my teacher told me to do everything in a table, couldn't you try to help this way?

Comment: I see, then create a [repro]. The other issue that causes it is the fixed height of `526px`. Eiter change it to a `min-height` or add an overflow-rule to the table.